# A weird error about GetDIBits and device context

Tags: c++, mfc, gdi, getdibits

A very weird problem I encountered today. Running codes below on VC6 with MFC project and it is black screen, it works perfectly and shows desktop picture if I take out the comment. However these codes are executed in a infinite loop, so I try to reduce memory copy and memory spend like `BitBlt` and `CreateCompatibleBitmap` etc. I do not understand how is my program related to these commented codes. Anyone knows what cause the problem and why?

```
HDC hdcDesktop = ::CreateDC("DISPLAY", NULL, NULL, NULL);
RECT desktopRect;
::GetWindowRect(::GetDesktopWindow(), &desktopRect);
int desktopWidth = desktopRect.right - desktopRect.left;
int desktopHeight = desktopRect.bottom - desktopRect.top;

HBITMAP hBitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdcDesktop, desktopWidth, desktopHeight);
/*
HDC hdcMemory = CreateCompatibleDC(hdcDesktop);
SelectObject(hdcMemory, hBitmap);
BitBlt(hdcMemory, 0, 0, desktopWidth, desktopHeight, hdcDesktop, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
*/

BITMAPINFO bitmapInfo = {0};
bitmapInfo.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);

GetDIBits(hdcDesktop, hBitmap, 0, 0, NULL, &bitmapInfo, DIB_RGB_COLORS);
BYTE *pData = new BYTE[bitmapInfo.bmiHeader.biSizeImage];
memset(pData, 0, bitmapInfo.bmiHeader.biSizeImage);
GetDIBits(hdcDesktop, hBitmap, 0, bitmapInfo.bmiHeader.biHeight, pData, &bitmapInfo, DIB_RGB_COLORS);

CRect destRect;
GetClientRect(&destRect);
StretchDIBits(::GetDC(m_hWnd), 0, 0, destRect.Width(), destRect.Height(), 0, 0, bitmapInfo.bmiHeader.biWidth, bitmapInfo.bmiHeader.biHeight, 
    pData, &bitmapInfo, DIB_RGB_COLORS, SRCCOPY);
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is not the place to ask for help, explaining **your** code. You should know, what your code does. And seriously, VC6? If you care about performance, upgrade to something that was written in this millennium.

Comment: I lot of project are still running in VC6, and they are stable and good ... I totally agree, it is an old compiler, but is reliable ... and the code from should work well in VC6 though.

Comment: @flaviu2: VC6 does not support **any** currently supported version of Windows (i.e. Windows Vista an up). There is nothing reliable about using a tool that does not support your targets. Plus, the group of developers that do actually still understand VC6's version of C++ is diminishingly small.

Answer (score 0):

Here's why commenting out the section doesn't work...

```
HBITMAP hBitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdcDesktop, desktopWidth, desktopHeight);

HDC hdcMemory = CreateCompatibleDC(hdcDesktop);
SelectObject(hdcMemory, hBitmap);

// BitBlt makes a copy of the desktop here.
BitBlt(hdcMemory, 0, 0, desktopWidth, desktopHeight, hdcDesktop, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

BITMAPINFO bitmapInfo = {0};
bitmapInfo.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);

// the following lines make use of the contents of bitmap in hBitmap
// commenting out the BitBlt would mean the bitmap is uninitialized.
//
GetDIBits(hdcDesktop, hBitmap, 0, 0, NULL, &bitmapInfo, DIB_RGB_COLORS);
BYTE *pData = new BYTE[bitmapInfo.bmiHeader.biSizeImage];
memset(pData, 0, bitmapInfo.bmiHeader.biSizeImage);  // <-- this is unnecessary.

GetDIBits(hdcDesktop, hBitmap, 0, bitmapInfo.bmiHeader.biHeight, pData, &bitmapInfo, DIB_RGB_COLORS);
```

You can optimize you code by creating a DIBSection, its associated BITMAPINFO and pData buffer at global scope for your app.  Its dimensions are valid for quite a bit of time... You'd have to watch out for changes to screen resolution by handling WM_DISPLAYCHANGE messages (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145210(v=vs.85).aspx).

This would save you the repeated call to CreateCompatibleBitmap().

There is no workaround that I can see to using BitBlt() and GetDIBits() for getting the desktop bits, though.